# Pass Anchor Value to Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, controller

I need to pass an id over to my controller but im not sure how to do it with the code that I have written.

This is my cshtml file:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#getDetails", function (e) {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetDetails',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html'
            })
            .success(function(result) {
                $('#detailsPlace').html(result);
            })
            .error(function(xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            });
    })
</script>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @*<input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="partId"/>*@
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" value="@item.Id" id="getDetails">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div id="detailsPlace"></div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var response = _test.GetParts("A");
    return View(response);
}

public ActionResult GetDetails()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

I just want to pass the value from

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" value="@item.Id" id="getDetails">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</a>
```

into my GetDetails() Controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors don't have "values".

So the first thing you should probably do is store that value in a data attribute.  Something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="@item.Id" id="getDetails">
```

Then in your AJAX call you can fetch it from that data attribute and pass it to the server.  Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/GetDetails',
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'myValue=' + $('#getDetails').data('value')
    dataType: 'html'
})
```

And in the controller action you can expect that `myValue` value.  Something like:

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(string myValue)
```

You can use whatever names and data types are appropriate throughout, these are just examples.  And of course there are other ways to do this as well.  But simply posting a single key/value pair like this should work.

---

***Note:*** It looks like you're using a static HTML `id` *in a loop*.  If more than one element has the same `id` then your HTML is invalid and the behavior of the JavaScript on that HTML is undefined.  `id` values should be unique in the HTML.

You're probably better off switching to a `class`.  For example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="@item.Id" class="getDetails">
```

You'd then have to adjust your selectors (JavaScript, CSS, etc.) accordingly of course.  And getting the value of the element which was clicked might not need a selector at all, this could work just as well:

```
$(this).data('value')
```

There are other, more semantic improvements which could also be made, such as using a button instead of an anchor since this isn't *really* behaving as an anchor.

Comment: It still isnt passing the value over, shall i just make it a button?

Comment: I just tried it using a button and using the value attribute and it still didnt work

Comment: @LukeRayner: Well, changing the element from an `a` to a `button` isn't so much a magic wand.  There are likely other changes you'd want/need to make to your code to accompany that change.  As for this "not working", can you be more specific?  What exact changes did you make?  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: I have made getDetails into a class and changed the Jquery to suit this, I added your data bit into my Jquery script and I add the parameter to the controller. Im not getting any errors the parameter is just returning null

Comment: `<button href="javascript:void(0)" value="@item.Id" class="getDetails">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</button>` this is what it looks like now

Comment: @LukeRayner: `button` elements don't have `href` attributes.  If your JavaScript code is looking for a `data-value` attribute, you don't have one.  (It's still `value`, which actually is valid for a `button` so you could use the `value` if you want to.)  A `button` may be posting the page instead of using the AJAX code, you would want to debug to find out.  And "the parameter is just returning null" doesn't really narrow down where the problem happens.  Is the AJAX call made?  Does it contain any value(s) at all?  You need to debug this.